# Omnibus GitLab version downgrade from 12.7.5 to 12.6.2

Tags: gitlab, centos6, gitlab-omnibus

Regarding Omnibus GitLab version downgrade from 12.7.5 to 12.6.2. Have followed the below steps.

1. Have taken the backup from 12.7.5 version.
2. Uninstalled the 12.7.5 version.
3. Installed 12.6.2 using rpm.
4. Tried to restore from backup file created from 12.7.5 tar file..

Message shows restore required same version(12.7.5).

I have gone the GitLab document. It says you can only restore a backup to exactly the same version was backup taken and type (CE/EE) of GitLab.

Can't find alternative method documents to roll back. So is there any way to downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab only [supports downgrading](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/README.html#downgrading) when you have an backup of your data that was created using the version you want to downgrade to (in your case 12.6.2).

In case you have one, you can simply restore the backup using the instructions provided in the link.

I'm not aware of any alternative to downgrade in case you don't have one.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have older version 12.6.2 backup file.